# How to send POST request with base64 image

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

#### The problem

I have been unable to find a source that describes a way to send an (base64) image over a POST request. I have tried to edit the signature so it accepts base64 images as input but with no success. Is it possible to change the model so that it accepts a (base64) image as input? If not, can I convert my created image to the correct format on my client?
Source code / logs

I am currently saving my keras model with standard signature using:

```js
tf.saved_model.save(model, "path")
```

The get requests result says the model is deployed:

```
{ "version": "4", "state": "AVAILABLE", "status": { "error_code": "OK", "error_message": "" } }
```

I am converting my image to base64 using the 'react-native-image-base64' library and sending it using a post request with the correct format.
However, as the error code says it expects a float

```
"error": "Failed to process element: 0 of \'instances\' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON Value: {"Base64 image string here"} Type: Object is not of expected type: float"
```

with the following request :

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://192.168.1.75:8501/v1/models/saved_model:predict \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '
{
   "instances":
   [
    {
       "b64": "HBwcIiIiIiIiHh4eGhoaGBgYExMTEBAQERERERERDw8PCQkJBQ.."
    }
   ]
}'
```

current signature def

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['conv2d_input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 102, 136, 3)
        name: serving_default_conv2d_input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['dense'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Comment: Can you please share your SignatureDef, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowSupport I am using the default signaturedef (aka no custom one). Do you know of a signaturedef in TF2 that uses base64 images as inputs?

Comment: You can get the SignatureDef by executing the command, `!saved_model_cli show --dir {export_path} --all`

Comment: @TensorflowSupport sorry for the late reply, i added the signaturedef to my original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **`SignatureDef`** indicates that Data Type of your Inputs is **`Float`**.

So, you can directly pass **`Float`** Value as Input and there is no need to convert it to **`Base64 Encoded Format`** because, we use **`Base64 Encoding`** when the **`Data Type`** of Input is **`String`**.

Code to Send Image over **`POST`** Request for Inference using **`grpc`** is shown below:

```
import grpc
import requests
import tensorflow as tf

import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

IMG_SIZE = 224

def main():

  img_array = cv2.imread('/content/daisy.jpg')
  new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  new_array = new_array / 255

  import json
  data = json.dumps(
    {"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": new_array.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3).tolist()})
  print('Data: {} ... {}'.format(data[:50], data[len(data) - 52:]))

  headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
  json_response = requests.post('http://35.226.32.128/v1/models/test0221/versions/1:predict', data=data, headers=headers)
  predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)['predictions']
  np.argmax(predictions[0])
  dicti
  for flower, label in dicti.items():
    if label == np.argmax(predictions[0]):
      print('Predicted Class is {}'.format(flower))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
Data: {"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": ... 6862745, 0.5019607843137255, 0.5176470588235295]]]]}

Predicted Class is Daisy
```

Comment: Thx! that makes everything alot clearer. is it also possible to convert the image without using OpenCV?

Comment: Yes, we can do it using `tf.keras.imagedatagenerator.load_img`, `img_to_array`, etc..

Comment: thx! You helped me get to the right path. I solved it using the DecodeJpeg function in tf-nodejs by converting the image to base64, sending it to the server and converting it to a uint8array there.